# How to create a rounded edges like this In Illustrator CS6 (Example included)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects

Sorry for such a newbie question. I tried google but can't find anything similar. I'm using Illustrator CS6 so I don't have CC's rounded corner tool. I tried *Effects > Stylize > Round Corners* but it doesn't work.

Here's what happens: (as you can see it distorts it)

[image]

I also tried applying a stroke to circle and removing the bottom half of circle then applying rounded caps to stroke but I don't like the final result.

Here's what I want to do.
[image]

This is what i have created by manually adjusting the corners using the pen tool but it looks pretty bad.

[image]

Comment: There's a tool (plugin) by Astute Graphics  called [Vectorscribe](https://astutegraphics.com/software/vectorscribe/) which will accomplish this for you. (it does cost money but they have a 14 day free trial)

Comment: @WELZ you should post this as an answer.

Comment: if round cap isn't good enough, I'd probably try the [round any corner script](https://github.com/Shanfan/Illustrator-Scripts-Archive/blob/master/jsx/Round%20Any%20Corner.jsx).

Comment: @WELZ This is the result of using effects>stylize>rounded corners https://imgur.com/a/cLsBk

Comment: You could draw some circles at that position instead of rounding the edges (enable the smart guides to snap each other. Crtl + U). Or... copy that rounded corner and flip it to the other parts.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this by going to *Effect → Stylize → Round Corners*
(not sure why it doesn't work)

There is a plugin from [Astute Graphics*](https://astutegraphics.com/software/vectorscribe/) (they charge, but have a 14 day trial), which is very good - my personal favorite.

<sub><sup>*I am not affiliated with Astute Graphics in any way</sup></sub>

Comment: After adding Anchor points. https://imgur.com/a/CQvDt

Answer (score 2):

Set up a path with a stroke.. and tick the "round end caps" option on the **Stroke Panel**.

[image]

If you then want these areas to be shapes rather than stroked paths... merely choose `Object > Expand` from the menu.

*"I don't like the final result"* is completely unclear.. Round caps apply *perfectly* rounded caps. Why is it "not liked" specifically? Why can't you adjust the paths after the cap is applied so you may like it?

Comment: Uhm.. no.. :)  `Object > Expand` as detailed in the answer. Outline stroke may work but often has different results in terms of construction.

Answer (score 0):

you can give rounded corner a radius use Effect → Stylize → Round Corners then give some radius of the rounded corner

Comment: This is the result of using effects>stylize>rounded corners imgur.com/a/cLsBk

Answer (score 0):

In the Layers panel, target the items you want to round.
If you want to round a specific attribute of an object, such as its fill or stroke, target the object in the Layers panel and then select the attribute in the Appearance panel.

Choose Effect > Stylize > Round Corners. (The command is located in the first Stylize sub-menu.)

To define the curvature of the rounded curve, enter a value in the Radius text box, and click OK.